# Creating an array of fields in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I am trying to implement program that will create an array out of the fields of a certain class
and then access each field

I have the following class:

```
public class Example {

  public int[] a = {1,2,3};
  public int[] b = {1,1,1};
  public int[] c = {2,2,2};
}
```

In a different class I want to access all of these fields and place them into the array "testArray"

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class Test { 

  Example t = new Example();
  Field[] testArray = t.getClass().getFields();

  for (Field elem: testArray) {
   // access the fields
  }

}
```

How can I access the fields this way?

NOTE: for some reasone this gives me an error of *Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token*

Comment: What is the difference? Don't both methods work?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank you for the small fix, but it still gives me the same error

Comment: Yeah, apparently they do, must have missed that memo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there: once you got an array of fields, call `get` on each one, passing the instance of the object from which you wish to get the property (in this case, that would be `t`):

```
Object[] fieldsOfT = new Object[testArray.length];
int i = 0;
for (Field f : testArray) {
    fieldsOfT[i++] = f.get(t);
}
for (Object v : fieldsOfT) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/KITpz3)

Of course this would not print pretty representations of the objects, because `int[]` arrays do not provide a meaningful `toString`, but you have the value there as an object, so you can cast it, and print the values as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because none of the code lives inside of a method. Move it into a test method.